# java lucene stopwords list

Tags: java, lucene, set, stop-words

i want to get lucene stop words list word by word.i can access whole set but when i iterate it,the output is not what i want

this is my code :

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
Set set=analyzer.getStopwordSet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

and in the console i see it:

```
[C@7ef955da
[C@23739c56
[C@7b1ce448
[C@25cf721d
[C@564ce14f
[C@515c35cc
[C@7cd00dce
```

Answer (score 1):

reason you are getting "[C@7ef955da" as out put is that you are treating `iterator.next()` as object in `System.out.println(...)` so it is printing its object's hashCode() in hex. Object return by `iterator.next()` is of type `char[]` so try to this

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
Set set=analyzer.getStopwordSet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println((char[])iterator.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` returned by [`getStopwordSet`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/StopwordAnalyzerBase.html#getStopwordSet%28%29) does not contain Strings, but rather char arrays.  Easy enough to convert though, simply by using the appropriate [String ctor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5b%5d%29):

```
Iterator<char[]> iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(new String(iterator.next()));
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, you're having trouble with types, since the iterator doesn't have a generic type declared, so it's trying to call new String(Object), which doesn't exist.  You can just cast the value returned from `iterator.next()` to `char[]`.  Or give it a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you cast the `iterator.next()` to a `char[]`. your iterator should look like this:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    char[] stopWord = (char[]) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(stopWord));
}
```